# Accessing onChange event from child component (React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a container component that's rendering a child component with an input. I would like to have access to the child component's value during the `onChange` event, but I am getting a "Proxy" object instead of the input value.

**Container Component**

```
...

class InputContainer extends React.Component {

    handleChange = (val) => {
        console.log(val);

        // => Proxy { [[Handler]]: Object, [[Target]]: SyntheticEvent, [[isRevoked]]: false }
    }

    render() {
        return <Input handleChange={this.handleChange} {...this.props} />;
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(InputContainer);
```

**Input Component**

```
export default function Input(props) {
    return <input onChange={props.handleChange} />;
}
```

*Why am I getting this "Proxy" object and how can I get the input's value from `InputContainer`?*

Comment: I'm assuming `hangleChange` is a typo in your question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are seeing is an instance of React's [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html). Note that everything will work the same, i.e this should work:

```
console.log('ev -> ', ev.target.value);
```

However, if you want to see the values in the Developer tools try:

```
console.log('ev -> ', ev.nativeEvent);
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

Quote:

> Your event handlers will be passed instances of SyntheticEvent, a cross-browser wrapper around the browser's native event. It has the same interface as the browser's native event, including stopPropagation() and preventDefault(), except the events work identically across all browsers.
>   If you find that you need the underlying browser event for some reason, simply use the nativeEvent attribute to get it.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly normal. You can access the value via `event.target.value`:

```
handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

[More info in the React docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a typing error, but you have `hangleChange` instead of `handleChange`. Anyway, `onChange` passes an `Event`-like object, value can be found in `event.target.value`

```
handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
```

[Read up on React's event system](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)

Comment: It was a typo. I guess I was caught off guard by the Synthetic Event. Thanks for the help!